# Append List of Strings to ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So I have a `List<T>` where type `T` is integers. Now I am retrieving this list from a function that uses a `SqlDataReader` to read my database records (DBMS: Sql Server). Essentially what I want to do is check that if the list say, returns the following:

```
1
7
4
```

I want to make a comparison to a string list (`List <string> outcome = new List<string>()`) where:

```
1 = apples
7 = bananas
4 = oranges
```

And finally add these strings to a list then bind them to a ComboBox control in my C# Windows Forms Application.

The problem with approach is that I am using an `if-condition` to check if the integer (which I am retrieving from the database) exists in the initial list which in this case we can call `List<int> checkInt = new List<int>()`) exists and if it is, add the string (`Banana, apple, oranges or whatever`) to the `outcome` list.

Below is my **actual** code:

```
  public List<int> getSubGroupsBelongingToUser()
        {
            List<int> DepartmentSubGroupIds = new List<int>();

            myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
            {
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@UserId", getUserID(cbxSelectUser.Text));
                mySQLCommand = new SqlCommand("Test", mySQLConnection);
                mySQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                mySQLConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                mySQLConnection.Open();

                SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    DepartmentSubGroupIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["DepartmentSubGroupId"]));
                }
            }
            return DepartmentSubGroupIds;
        }
```

So the function above will return `1 and 3`. And I call it as below:

```
  private List<string> getSubGroupPerID()
        {
            List<string> outcome = new List<string>();

            if (getSubGroupsBelongingToUser().Contains(1))
            {
                outcome.Add("Apple");
            }
            else if (getSubGroupsBelongingToUser().Contains(2))
            {
                outcome.Add("Oranges");
            }
            else if (getSubGroupsBelongingToUser().Contains(3))
            {
                outcome.Add("Pineapples");
            }           
            else
            {
                outcome.Add("All");
            }
            return outcome;
        }
```

Now the problem is that, once it executes, the compiler will check the if-condition and if its true, it will `only` add that one fruit and finish execution (which is correctly how an if-condition gets executed). But I want it to check all the `.Contains(int)` and if those comparisons meet then add the fruits only at the end. I already know what the problem is, me using an if-condition. How can I get the result that I want after taking the above into cognisance?

**Note:** Due to time constraints, I didn't alter my actual code to match the fruit example I gave but surely you should get what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary` for that:

```
    Dictionary<int, string> fruit = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    fruit.Add(1, "Apple");
    fruit.Add(2, "Oranges");
    fruit.Add(3, "Pineapple");

    private List<string> getSubGroupPerID()
    {
        List<string> outcome = new List<string>();
        List<int> keys = getSubGroupsBelongingToUser();

        if(keys.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(int key in keys)
            {
                outcome.Add(fruit[key]);
            }
        }      
        else
        {
            outcome.Add("All");
        }

        return outcome;
    }
```

If you prefer the pattern you were using, the problem is that you `if-else` there. That means, if the first condition was true the others won't be checked. You can solve this by only using `if` and then check if anything was added:

```
    private List<string> getSubGroupPerID()
    {
        List<string> outcome = new List<string>();

        if (getSubGroupsBelongingToUser().Contains(1))
        {
            outcome.Add("Apple");
        }
        if (getSubGroupsBelongingToUser().Contains(2))
        {
            outcome.Add("Oranges");
        }
        if (getSubGroupsBelongingToUser().Contains(3))
        {
            outcome.Add("Pineapples");
        }           
        if(outcome.Count == 0)
        {
            outcome.Add("All");
        }
        return outcome;
    }
```

Comment: What I would have said except I would have used Linq ```var outcome = subgroups.Select(f=> fruit[f]).ToList();``` and initialised the dictionary on declaration ```Dictionary<int, string> fruits = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {1,"apples"},
    {4,"bananas"},
    {7,"oranges"}
};```